# Flutter Session API Login

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am trying to log in with the help of API and after login wants to see dashboard.
but I am getting a message {status: error, message: Seller Not Logged In}
I tried creating a session of login but it didn't work.

Login Page

```
postMethod() async {
var api = Uri.parse("https://www.nearxt.com/index.php?route=api/userlogin");
Map mapeddate ={
  'email':_email.text,
   'password':_password.text,
};
  final response= await post(api,body: mapeddate);
  if(response.statusCode==200)
  {
    await FlutterSession().set('token',_email.text);
    print("Session Created");
  }
   var res = json.decode(response.body);
    print(res);
 }
```

**it gives the output: Session Created
{cust: Login Success, error_warning: , success: }**

after this, on homepage, I am trying to access the products after the login

```
  Future fetchSellerProduct() async {
   FlutterSession().get('token');
  var url = await http.post(Uri.parse(
     "https://www.nearxt.com/index.php?route=api/purpletree_multivendor/api/sellerproduct"));
  if(url.statusCode==200)
 {
   print(url.statusCode);
 }
 setState(() {
    map = json.decode(url.body);
  print(map);
  });
 }
```

**Output: {status: error, message: Seller Not Logged In}**

Comment: Try adding the `JWT` at the headers of your `post` requests to check if the issue with the `Flutter session` package.

Comment: i don't get it 
in which function i need to add JWT

Comment: At your post request : `var url = await http.post(Uri.parse("https://www.nearxt.com/index.php?route=api/purpletree_multivendor/api/sellerproduct"),{"Authorization": "Some token"});`

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Check their API docs to see how they handle the authorization, maybe you are missing something. The error is a bit vague.

Comment: Alright Brother

Comment: Bro Can You help me out. I am really stuck in this problem for so long

Comment: You're setting 'token' as '_email.text' but I think you should save the Auth token returned by API UserLogin method